# How to show the dataTable in c# console?

Tags: c#

I have create a simple program to read from the txt file to load the data to `DataTable`. But how can I display the `DataTable` info in the console? The `Console.Write` / `Console.WriteLine` does not accept the `DataTable` as a parameter?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CompareLinuxWithWindow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample.txt", 10);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
                tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));


            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var cols = line.Split(',');

                DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
                for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < 10; cIndex++)
                {
                    dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
                }

                tbl.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

            return tbl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use following :             foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString())));
            }

Comment: For one, you're parsing the file (good) and discarding the result in `Main`.  Save it into a variable and iterate row by row and column by column, applying any formating you might want.

Comment: @jdweng The code I should apply inside the main or ConvertToDataTable? I'm new to C# :(

Comment: You should change first list to : DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample.txt", 10);  You current code only has the table defined locally inside ConvertToTable.   Once you modify code then you can put my loop either place.

Comment: Can already. But actually any different convert txt file to dataTable compare to directly WriteLine for the txt file.

Both of the txt file context assume like this 
sometext1,sometext2,sometext3,sometext4,sometext5,sometext6,sometext7,sometext8,sometext9,sometext10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Please try this

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace CompareLinuxWithWindow
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        DataTable dt= ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample.txt", 10);
        DataTable dt2= ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample.txt2", 10);

        //Add these lines
        for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++) //looping through all rows including the column. change `i=1` if need to exclude the columns display
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) //looping through all columns
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i][j]); //display of the data
            }
        }
        //End of change

        //Added for 2nd txt file
       for(int i=0;i<dt2.Rows.Count;i++) //looping through all rows including the column. change `i=1` if need to exclude the columns display
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Columns.Count; j++) //looping through all columns
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dt2.Rows[i][j]); //display of the data
            }
        }
       //End :: Added for 2nd txt file
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
            tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));


        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var cols = line.Split(',');

            DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
            for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < numberOfColumns; cIndex++)//changed hardcoded value of 10 to numberOfColumns
            {
                dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
            }

            tbl.Rows.Add(dr);

        }

        return tbl;
    }
}
}
```

Kindly let me know if this helps.

Comment: It works, but can I load from 2 text file. Because it show that it has been use by another process. When I read from this DataTable dt2= ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample2.txt", 10);

Comment: @apple, I created `DataTable dt2= ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample2.txt", 10);`. It works for me. Please explain more in detail

Comment: I read the 2txt file by put like this..
DataTable dt= ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample1.txt", 10);
DataTable dt2= ConvertToDataTable(@"C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample2.txt", 10);

but once I execute it in the line
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);   It show me error message System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sampel1.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: I updated the answer , its working for me. Please try n let me know.

Comment: It still show out the error message in the line string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\manchunl\Desktop\Sample2.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: It's seems like is my second txt file problem. I will check on it. But your solution above works for me when I try replace the second path way read the same txt file with the 1st one

Comment: Cheers. :)  please if you can upvote for this answer by clicking on above the "zero" on the left of the answer.